# scan.hasNextDouble() not working?

Tags: java

I've typed the code from my Java textbook word for word into my code. The output file has nothing printed and I've tried changing my code so it prints the results to the console rather than an output file.

Neither works and I'm lost. Please help!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class InputOutput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inputFileName = ("myFile.txt");
        String outputFileName = ("myOutputFile.txt");

        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

        while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            double value = scan.nextDouble();
            out.println(value);
        }

        scan.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Text File:

```
AL Alabama 350 - 369
AK Alaska 995 - 999
AZ Arizona 850 - 865
AR Arkansas 716 - 729 
CA California 900 - 966
CO Colorado 800 - 816
```

Comment: What's in myFile.txt?

Comment: your program reads floating point values from myFile.txt. if that file is empty, or doesn't start with a valid value (e.g., '10', '0.1', '3.1'), then the loop ends before anything is ever printed.

Comment: I edited and gave a small fraction of the file.

Comment: `AL` isn't a floating point number, and you don't read anything from the scanner if you don't see one, so nothing is ever going to happen.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood. I thought it went through the file and grabbed any floating points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first token has to be a number for your while loop to engage at least once.

You probably intend to extract just the numbers?

try this instead:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
     double value = scan.nextDouble();
     out.println(value);
   } else {
     scan.next();
   }
}
```